# Using C#, what's an efficient way to compare/merge two generic lists of the same type?

Tags: c#, generics

If I have two generic lists, List, and I want to merge all the unique Place objects into one List, based on the Place.Id property, what's a good method of doing this efficiently?

One list will always contain 50, the other list could contain significantly more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid having to define your own ElementComparer and just use lambda expressions, you can try the following:

```
List<Place> listOne = /* whatever */;
List<Place> listTwo = /* whatever */;
List<Place> listMerge = listOne.Concat(
                           listTwo.Where(p1 => 
                               !listOne.Any(p2 => p1.Id == p2.Id)
                           )
                        ).ToList();
```

Essentially this will just concatenate the Enumerable listOne with the set of all elements in listTwo such that the elements are not in the intersection between listOne and listTwo.

Comment: I like this solution. What are the downsides? Anything I should look out for? One list will only ever have 50 object max, but the other list could have thousands!

Comment: Well, this is pretty much your standard `union`. It should be pretty efficient in your case, and the IEnumerable.Any() extension is nice because it short-circuits (i.e as soon as it succeeds in matching once, it returns true and won't continue iterating through the collection). Of course, you could get more fancy and order your 50-object List and then write your own EqualityComparer to binary search the list, but in my opinion this should be fine for you. Do your own tests and see if its efficient for you.

Comment: I just did some quick benchmarking, investing time in writing your own IEqualityComparer interface is well worth the time compared to the above.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407#snippetGroup

Answer (score 2):

```
result = list1.Union(list2, new ElementComparer());
```

You need to create ElementComparer to implement IEqualityComparer. E.g. see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[Enumerable.Distinct Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx)

Note: .NET 3.5 & above.

Comment: You'd first need to join the sets together.

Comment: True. Totally forgot about that.
Then this method won't meet the OP requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to emphasize efficiency, I suggest you write a small method to do the merge yourself:

```
List<Place> constantList;//always contains 50 elements. no duplicate elements
List<Place> targetList;
List<Place> result;

Dictionary<int, Place> dict;
for(var p in constantList)
   dict.Put(p.Id,p);

result.AddRange(constantList);

for(var p in targetList)
{
   if(!dict.Contains(p.Id))
       result.Add(p)       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If speed is what you need, you need to compare using a Hashing mechanism. What I would do is maintain a Hashset of the ids that you have already read and then add the elements to the result if the id hasn't been read yet. You can do this for as many lists as you want and can return an IEnumerable instead of a list if you want to start consuming before the merge is over.

```
 public IEnumerable<Place> Merge(params List<Place>[] lists)
 {
     HashSet<int> _ids = new HashSet<int>();
     foreach(List<Place> list in lists)
     {
         foreach(Place place in list)
         {
             if (!_ids.Contains(place.Id))
             {
                 _ids.Add(place.Id);
                 yield return place;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

The fact that one list has 50 elements and the other one many more has no implication. Unless you know that the lists are ordered...